# Why doesn't my MASM32 x86 Assembly selection sort code sort properly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32, selection-sort

I'm trying to get a sort selection program running in MASM32 x86 Assembly and it's not really working the way I want. I'm using the IRVINE32 library for some functions like Randomize and Random32. The output I get is a comma separated list of numbers which aren't sorted. I'm new to assembly and Visual Studio. My code is below:

```
;----------------SELECTION SORT PROC------------------
;Procedure to sort an array
;Receives: Array OFFSET in EAX, array size in EBX
;Returns: Sorted array using same offsets
 
 
Sort PROC
LOCAL arraySize:DWORD
LOCAL min:DWORD
MOV arraySize, EBX
 
PUSHAD
;ESI - Outer loop counter
;ECX - Inner loop counter
 
MOV ESI, 0
OUTER:                               ; for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    DEC arraySize
    CMP ESI, arraySize
    INC arraySize
    JAE FINISHED
 
    MOV min, ESI
    INC ESI
    MOV ECX, ESI
    DEC ESI
    INNER:                           ; for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        CMP ECX, arraySize
        JAE IFSTATEMENT2
 
        IFSTATEMENT1:                ; if(array[j] < array[min])
            MOV EBX, ECX
            SHL EBX, 2               ; becomes j*4
            MOV EDX, [EAX + EBX]     ; becomes array[j]
 
            MOV EBX, 0
            MOV EBX, min
            SHL EBX, 2
 
            CMP EDX, [EAX + EBX]
            JGE SKIP_UPDATE
 
            MOV min, ECX
            SKIP_UPDATE:
                INC ECX
                JMP INNER
 
    IFSTATEMENT2:                   ;if (min != i)
        CMP min, ESI
        JE ENDIF2
        PUSH ESI
        PUSH ECX
 
        MOV EDX, 0
        MOV EBX, 0
        MOV ESI, 0
        MOV ECX, 0
 
        SHL ESI, 2
 
        MOV EDX, [EAX + ESI]         ; int temp = array[i]
        MOV ECX, min
        SHL ECX, 2                   ; here ECX equals the index of min
        MOV EBX, [EAX + ECX]     
        MOV [EAX + ESI], EBX         ; array[i] = array[min]
        MOV [EAX + ECX], EDX         ; array[min] = temp;
 
        POP ECX
        POP ESI
 
    ENDIF2:
        INC ESI
        JMP OUTER
 
FINISHED:
    POPAD
    ret
    Sort ENDP
 
 
;----------------MAIN PROC------------------
;Procedure that generates 10 random 32 bit signed integer values and sorts them 
 
; Not including full code, just the call to the function because stack overflow doesn't like posting full code I think

    MOV EAX, OFFSET myData
    MOV EBX, 10d
    CALL Sort
```

I've rewrote this code a couple times to no avail, I have asked AI which is no help, I attempted to debug on visual studio but it's just foreign language to me, I'm really uncomfortable with the format. The main code does work fine (it does produce random 32 bit unsigned integers), unless the call to the procedure and setting up the parameters is wrong, then the only issue is in the sort portion. I dont THINK it's an issue with unsigned vs signed values, I checked the jumps I used were correct for signed and unsigned, the logic looks good to me, I'm not really sure where to go.

Comment: What problem did you run into while debugging? It's a simple matter, just keep stepping instructions one by one and verify each does what you want.

Comment: I just didn't really know how lol. There's like breakpoints and call stacks and whatnot with a bunch of hex values and i just have no idea how that all works, so it didnt really help me. I just mentioned it because I know people would ask what the debugger says and my answer is I don't really know lol

Comment: The time it take learning to use a debugger is one of the most valuable things you could spend time on for learning assembly.  There's a section at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info about debugging, with a link to a Q&A about using the debugger in visual studio for asm.  The machine state is just the registers and the current program counter; that's already the model of execution you should be thinking about when you write the program, and the debugger can show it to you directly.  Single-stepping (not just breakpoints) is very useful.

Comment: Please make sure to keep your comments on topic for the question to contribute to a more efficient stack overflow. Learning how to use a debugger was not my intention, and your comment does not provide any further clarification to help the question being solved.

Comment: Start debugging with a very small input size, like 1 element, then go to 2 elements, etc..   Also, have a C or other language version to compare with every step of the way, so you know what it should be doing and when, what values its looking at and what it is swapping, etc...

Comment: One obvious problem is the `MOV ESI, 0` in the `IFSTATEMENT2` block. That clears the value of `i`. None of the other zeroes are needed since you set all of those registers later, but at least those are not harmful.

Comment: I push ESI to the stack before those operations and pop them after, therefore restoring the original value of i. The reason I set zero's is I'm just not familiar with how things are stored in registers and how the mov instruction exactly works (whether it entirely clears the register before moving or just overwrites idk)

Comment: `SHL ESI, 2` well you zeroed `ESI` so that's just constant zero. `MOV EDX, [EAX + ESI] ; int temp = array[i]` no, it's not `array[i]` because, as I said, `ESI` is zero. It's `array[0]`. Always.

Comment: oh you're 100% right wtf hold on let me boot up my vm and try this out

Comment: Yeah I mean wow it worked. Im honestly shocked cause I didnt do that before and it didnt work, but yeah thank you so much, I dont think I'm able to mark comments as answers? if you want to create an answer I'll mark it correct for you thank you so much again.

Comment: This is the kind of problem that isn't helpful to future readers; all you (and others in your situation) know is that their sort code doesn't work.  The chances of future readers having the exact same bug (zeroing a register they shouldn't have) is minimal.  This is why Stack Overflow debugging questions [expect that people have already checked with a debugger to find mistakes like this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), as well as providing a mcve.  Your specific problem was this bug, but it was a symptom of the general problem of not yet having learned to use a debugger.